# java как узнать по дате день недели?

Tags: java, android

java как узнать по дате день недели? Пример: 29.11.2016 нужно получить 29.11.2016 = "Вторник";

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
c.setTime(yourDate);
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: а как с учетом того, что начало недели там с воскресенья?

Comment: @КонстантинСмирнов используйте метод setFirstDayOfWeek